# Как объединить две таблицы разной величины в MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеются две таблицы: в tbl_1 - 3 поля, в tbl_2 - те же 3 поля + еще 2.

```
      tbl_1               tbl_2
id | name | age |       id | name | age | mother | father
1    Дима   19          3    Катя   18+   Ольга    Игорь
2    Петя   20          4    Маша   18+   Марина   Степан
```

Мой вопрос в том, можно ли склеить эти две таблицы в следующем виде?

```
tbl_3
id | name | age | mother | father
3  | Катя | 18+ | Ольга  | Игорь
4  | Маша | 18+ | Марина | Степан
1  | Дима | 19  |        |
2  | Петя | 20  |        |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать `UNION/UNION ALL` для объединения двух запросов `SELECT`. При этом придется явно перечислять поля, а также для таблицы, где данные колонки отсутствуют придется дописывать выборку NULL. Примерно так:

```
Select id, column1, null as column2 from tableA // тут column2 отсутствует в tableA 
UNION ALL
Select id, column1, column2 from tableB
```

А вообще логика построения таблиц неверная. Во-первых не должно быть двух таблиц с одинаковыми сущностями. Во-вторых надо делать ссылку на родственника,  а не прописывать его непосредственно в ту же строку. То есть должна быть колонка `parent_id`, которая будет указывать на идентификатор предка в некоторой таблице, в которой описаны его данные (возможно это был бы идентификатор на ту же таблицу)